# LG optimus P-500 firmware update: PC suite for Linux?

Tags: updates, linux, device-firmware, lg-optimus-one

My phone, a *LG Optimus P-500* requested to be connected to the *PC suite* in order to perform a firmware update (the official one).

I don't have the *PC suite* and have only access to Linux computers. The *PC suite* (probably [this one](http://lg-pc-suite.soft32.com/)?) is only available for Windows. Is there a way to perform the update? Can I run the *PC suite* in *wine*?

thank you

---

*Update:* Apparently *wine* [cannot handle](http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?p=50021&sid=47b1e6d371f98c23b3ce330c538a4fee) it.

Comment: +1, I would love to see producers starting finally noticing Linux (I don't know the answer, though)

Answer (score 2):

You may try to run Windows copy in VirtualBox. VB has ability to connect physical USB devices to virtual machine. So Windows will detect your phone. 
BUT BEWARE! Using such way for flash your phone may render it unusable (brick your phone, in another words). It is good to make sync between phone and PC.

Also I'd like to see native Linux version of PC Suite too.

Comment: i've used virtualbox for similar situations (flashing and installing ROMs) and it's worked for me. this sounds like an excellent solution! +1

Comment: @jlehenbauer and did you have difficulty with flashing? I find it hard to believe that it worked - because you know why? The handset would have to go through a reboot  or two after a flash, the flasher software will realize the usb gets disconnected within the virtualbox itself and that's where the trouble can arise... either you have to be quick to reconnect the usb for the flasher software to say "successful" I call shenanigans on that - if you want to flash, use a real windows machine for now, not a virtualbox. :)

Comment: There's heimdall for Linux, but that's mostly Samsung orientated for a small specific set of models. But yeah it would be nice to see a real port of the software for Linux but meh... :)